# How can i get client side mandatory field validation on htmleditor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

net MVC4 
my problem is on form submit time i am not getting client side validation on htmleditor,
but i am getting company name's mandatory field validation,than i am not creating any jquery validation. please help me

***This is my  Model***

```
namespace smetiger.Models
{
public class BusinessProfile
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter About Company")]
    [Display(Name = "About Company : ")]
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string txtAboutCompany { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Company Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name : ")]
    public string txtCompanyName { get; set; }        

}
```

***This is my  View***

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
</div>
```

Comment: TinyMCE replaces the original textarea with a custom one. Then you are loosing all the `data-*` validation attributes that were present and thus no validation occurs. You will have to make custom validation for this specific field.

Comment: may i use to any html-editor which is provide validation, message arrive from model.please help me.

Comment: Yes, it might be possible but as I said you will have to implement custom validation.

Comment: i have 14 to 20 fields in my page,and first i try to custom validation for these two html-editor, but at that time other mandatory validation error message not appear, means first these html editor message is fire, and if it is not blank than other is show.